# How to get below format output data from Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

expected output example: {count of job:number,sum of assets:number,count of job group by status:number,list of policy:policyname +policyid}.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("653b3aa1a32c44a477d78ad4"),
    "name" : "Job1",
    "remediationPolicy" : {
        "policyId" : "65005f5511e76f43eb624727",
        "policyName" : "Sample Remedition Policy"
    },
    "batches" : [
        {
            "name" : "batch6",
            "scheduleDetails" : {
                "startDate" : "2023-10-11T06:30:00.000Z",
                "recurrenceType" : "No Recurrence",
                "isRecurring" : false,
                "scheduleType" : "On Demand"
            },
            "assets" : [
                {
                    "deviceId" : "iox-sample-121",
                    "deviceName" : "iox-sample",
                    "controllerId" : "Nso Test",
                    "subControllerId" : "rfs-1",
                    "controllerType" : "Nso-1"
                }
            ],
            "remediationPolicy" : {
                "policyId" : "65005f5511e76f43eb624727",
                "policyName" : "Sample Remedition Policy"
            },
            "jobDetails" : {
                "jobid" : "653b3aa1a32c44a477d78ad4",
                "jobname" : "Job5"
            },
            "commit" : false,
            "totalAssets" : 1,
            "userName" : "admin",
            "tenant" : "0d6a4690-63e6-11ed-9a7f-499f293f346d",
            "status" : "Draft"
        }
    ],
    "commit" : true,
    "cancel" : false,
    "archive" : false,
    "ticket" : "0123456789",
    "totalAssets" : 1,
    "batchSummary" : {
        "queued" : 0,
        "running" : 0,
        "cancelled" : 0,
        "completed" : 0
    },
    "statusDetails" : {
        "draft" : "Completed",
        "commit" : "In Progress",
        "remediate" : "Not Started",
        "completed" : "Not Started"
    },
    "userName" : "admin",
    "tenant" : "0d6a4690-63e6-11ed-9a7f-499f293f346d",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-10-27T04:20:49.341Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-10-27T09:40:28.990Z")
}
```

expected output example: {count of job:number,sum of assets:number,count of job group by status:number,list of policy:policyname +policyid}.

Comment: Please format your data for better readability.